# link fire store database with two flutterapp

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

please I have a question  about if can I link the same fire store database to two flutter applications ,the first one is to be used by the manager and the second to be used by the client?, if not what the better way to achieve that?
thank you very much:>

Answer (score 1):

no issue about multiple flutter or other app in same firebase project. You can connect your second app just like first app connection process.

**Step 1:** Add app from your firebase project Project Overview and select your platform

[image]

**Step 2:** Register app with your second app package name

[image]

**Step 3:** And download json file and using this json file you can connect your second app within same procedure just like you apply for  first app

[image]